# /dev/sda clean loop & Nouveau errors

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 20.04, nouveau

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for a while now, and up until today, everything was fine. When I booted up my computer today, it stuck on the `/dev/sda` clean message. Having dealt with this before, I figured it'd be no big deal, just uninstall and reinstall the NVIDIA drivers with the following, since that's fixed it before.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

That didn't work, I got stuck on `/dev/sda` again. I tried to wait it out, but the message would go away, leaving a blank screen with just an underscore, and then flash again to `/dev/sda` clean. So, I uninstalled NVIDIA drivers and just left it as is with Nouveau. I can boot with just Nouveau, but something seems to be running abnormally hot as my fan is much louder than it was before with NVIDIA. I also get the following screen full of Nouveau errors before it ends up booting (pardon the dust).

[image]

So, I'm pretty lost here. I've `nomodeset` to no avail, manually installing NVIDIA drivers, automatically installing NVIDIA drivers, installing older drivers, and nothing's helping. Is there anything I can do to get Ubuntu to boot with NVIDIA drivers, or at least fix whatever the Nouveau errors are about, or should I just do a fresh OS install?

I'm not too Linux-literate, so patience is appreciated.